Explaining Arithmetic Progression
So first introduction to a kid to arithmetic progression is when they see this, For every value of n, the sum 1+2+3+...+n of the first n integers is equal to n(n+1)/2. So a kid asked sir why is n used as value in 1+2+3+..+n, when n is the count of numbers in the series 1+2+3+...n. I am not able to decide whether that's a valid question or if it is how explain that why n is used thay way or it is both count as well as value!!!

It's both. What's the problem?

@DanielR.Collins That's my reaction to the question too. Is it somehow strange that in the expression 1+2+3  , 3 is the last number and there are 3 numbers? I feel like I'm misunderstanding the question.

@DanielR.Collins How it is both, that's the question. Is it beacuse of the way Natural Numbers are constructed?!

You should probably distinguish between a sequence and a series.  The latter calls for evaluating a summation, while the former simply defines a number list that can be extended indefinitely.

I don't understand what's really being Asked here, but except ion very special circumstances not relevant here, isn't the using any variable as both count and value anathema? Wouldn't the simplest solution be to use 'n' for one and 'N' for the other… if that broke no other rules?

@RobbieGoodwin I think it is important to explain both, Why n=last value and also why n=count. Thanks for the comment.

Thanks and is 'It's important to explain both…' your explanation?
I still think the kid was right and the same identity - here 'n' - should never be given to different variable.

The kid is right:
Imagine the sum of the first odd numbers: $1+3+5+7+...$, or the sum of the first even numbers: $2+4+6+8+...$ or the sum of the first multiples of $17$: $17+34+51+68+...$, how do you write those?
Well, you can state that any odd number can be written as $2n+1$, so:
$1+3+5+7+... = (1)+(3)+(5)+(7)+... = (2 \cdot 0 + 1) + (2 \cdot 1 + 1) + (2 \cdot 2 + 1) + (2 \cdot 3 + 1) + ...$
Any even number can be written as $2n$, so:
$2+4+6+8+... = (2) + (4) + (6) + (8) + ... = (2 \cdot 1) + (2 \cdot 2) + (2 \cdot 3) + (2 \cdot 4) + ...$
The first multiples of $17$ can be written as:
$17 + 34 + 51 + 68 + ... = (17) + (34) + (51) + (68) + ... = (17 \cdot 1) + (17 \cdot 2) + (17 \cdot 3) + (17 \cdot 4) + ...$
If you dare telling this, the kid will immediately react that once, you start counting from $0$ and two times you start counting from $1$, and also there the kid is right.
Two means to solve this:

In order to count from $1$ every time, you need to write an odd number, not as $2n+1$ (the smallest odd number ($1$) is defined for $n=0$) but as $2n-1$ (the smallest odd number ($1$) is defined for $n=1$).
Write the multiples (of $2$ or of $17$ or of whatever number), not as $2+4+6+8+...$ but as $0+2+4+6+...$, and not as $17+34+51+68+...$ but as $0+17+34+51+...$. Like this, you always start with $n=0$.

I advise you to use the second approach: writing any odd number, using a subtraction, is not a good idea and in top of that: $\sum{2n+1} = n^2$, which is easy, while $\sum{2n-1}=(n-1)^2$, which is confusing.
Kid: "But sir: if we then write $1+2+3+...+n$ as $0+1+2+...+n$, then the amount won't reflect the number."
You: "Did I ever say mathematics is easy? :-)"

Hi,
In addition to your answer this answer by chatGPT and some reading did it for me:
The reason it's valid to use  as both a count and the last value in the series 1+2+3+⋯+ is deeply tied to the construction of natural numbers. In the natural number system,  represents both the position and the value due to the sequential and ordered way the numbers are built. This relationship is what makes the sum formula
(+1)/2 work, as it relies on the count  being the value of the last term in the series.

Try different examples where n is not both a value and the number of terms? e.g. 2 + 4 + 6 + ... + 2k, where k is a positive whole number. Or 5 + 7 + 9 + 11 + ... + (2k + 1) where k is a positive whole number starting from 2. And so on ...
Yes a bit more challenging than your original example but this is education, right?

Natural numbers are commonly called "counting numbers" in elementary education. For example, the meaning of the natural number $3$ is precisely that you've counted $3$ things. Having counted $n$ things, we define that to be the natural number $n$. That's exactly what the value $n$ means.
If the student is truly advanced, then you can entertain introducing them to the Dedekind–Peano axioms which formally define the natural numbers in this way. But I think you'd need to be in a highly unusual situation for that to be beneficial.

But is it ok to use n as value in 1+2+3+...+n. Is it just because it makes the calculations easier?!

@AshishShukla: It's okay, because it clarifies that the count is the same thing as the last value counted. By analogy, "Jack and Jill went up the hill... Jack fell down" would be less clear if for some reason we used a different name for Jack going up versus down.

The $n$th term of an arithmetic progression with start_term $u_1$ and common difference $d$ is:
$$u_n = u_1 + (n-1) d$$
This formula is a bit nicer if the terms are 0-indexed instead of 1-indexed:
$$u_n = u_0 + n d$$
(The drawback of 0-indexing is that the number of terms up to "the $n$th term" becomes $n+1$, not just $n$.)
In your particular case, $d = 1$ and $u_1 = 1$ (or $u_0 = 0$), therefore $u_n = n$.
In a sense you can consider it a "coincidence" that $u_n$ and $n$ are equal.
Since $u_k = k$ is true for all $k$, you didn't even feel it necessary to introduce this $u_{...}$ notation at all, and the $k$th term is just $k$.
Another noteworthy coincidence is that the sum of the integers from 0 to n and the sum of the integers from 1 to n are equal.
